# T-SQL to PL/SQL - Use temporary variables and the "INTO" expression to search the total of a query in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, t-sql

In sql below I return the search between the tables and then return the total of this already paginated.

The need to return this total is to paginate

That query is using sql server.

Sql server:

```
  SELECT
        bu.Id as 'BarcoUsuarioId',
        Barco_Id as 'BarcoId',
        bu.Usuario_Id as 'UsuarioId',
        barco.Nome as 'NomeBarco'
  into #tmpBarcoUsuario
  FROM BARCO_USUARIO AS bu
  inner join BARCO as barco on barco.Id = bu.Barco_Id
  where bu.Usuario_Id = @usuarioId

  declare @totalEmbarcacoes as int = (select count(*) from #tmpBarcoUsuario);
  select
        BarcoUsuarioId,
        BarcoId,
        UsuarioId,
        NomeBarco, 
   @totalEmbarcacoes as TotalEmbarcacoes from #tmpBarcoUsuario
   order by BarcoId
   OFFSET @pageSize *(@pageNumber - 1) ROWS
   fetch next @pageSize ROWS ONLY";
```

However, when using the Oracle database, I having some difficulty.

As can be seen in sql below, I already made the pagination query in oracle DB:

Oracle:

```
SELECT  *                           
              FROM(
              SELECT ROWNUM rnum, b.* 
              FROM (
              SELECT 
                   barcoUser.ID BarcoUsuarioId  ,
                   barcoUser.BARCO_ID BarcoId  ,
                   barcoUser.USARIO_ID UsuarioId  ,
                   barco.NOME NomeBarco 
              FROM BARCO_USUARIO barcoUser INNER JOIN EMBARCACAO barco ON barco.ID = barcoUser.BARCO_ID
              WHERE (barcoUser.USARIO_ID=:usuarioId)ORDER BY BarcoId DESC
               )b 
              )WHERE RNUM between :PageSize * (:PageNumber - 1) AND  (:PageSize * :PageNumber)";
```

but how would I do to return the total of all this already paginated, as was done in sql server?

Comment: Maybe [count](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/count-analytic-function) like this: `count(1) over() as TotalEmbarcacoes`?

Comment: Oracle (12c+) does support the `OFFSET .. ROWS FETCH NEXT .. ROWS ONLY` syntax, btw.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the analytic `count(*)` function

```
        SELECT  *                           
          FROM(
          SELECT ROWNUM rnum, b.* 
          FROM (
          SELECT 
               barcoUser.ID BarcoUsuarioId  ,
               barcoUser.BARCO_ID BarcoId  ,
               barcoUser.USARIO_ID UsuarioId  ,
               barco.NOME NomeBarco ,
               count(*) over () TotalCount
          FROM BARCO_USUARIO barcoUser 
               INNER JOIN EMBARCACAO barco ON barco.ID = barcoUser.BARCO_ID
         WHERE (barcoUser.USARIO_ID=:usuarioId)
         ORDER BY BarcoId DESC
           )b 
          )
       WHERE RNUM between :PageSize * (:PageNumber - 1) 
                    AND  (:PageSize * :PageNumber)
```

Note that Oracle has supported the `OFFSET FETCH` syntax since 12c if you want to minimize the changes between database engines.  The `rownum` approach, however, may be faster than the `OFFSET FETCH` approach.